# How to change the color of mouse cursor in magic mouse js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, frontend

I'm using magic mouse js for my website, and it's coming in white. but my website have some white elements, so when hovering over those the mouse is not visible enough. So i want to change the color of the cursor so it can be visible enough. It's better if i could change the cursor color on certain parts. like in section 1 it could be red, in section 2 it could be blue. like wise

I was able to completely change the cursor but not the color. i want to change the color only.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/veseylab/raw/upload/v1684982764/magicmouse-2.0.0.cdn.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    options = {
    "cursorOuter": "circle-basic",
    "hoverEffect": "circle-move", 
    "hoverItemMove": false,
    "defaultCursor": false,
    "outerWidth": 30,
    "outerHeight": 30
      };
    magicMouse(options);
  </script>
```

Comment: Add your code, no one is able to guess what you did so far

Comment: So now we need to go google what *"magic mouse js"* is, read the docs, imagine the code you have... Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the magic mouse cursor/pointer by using the css property `background: #fff`

Answer (score 0):

```
var magicCustomPointer = document.querySelector('#magicPointer');
var magicCustomCursor = document.querySelector('#magicMouseCursor');
```

Here can be customized for height, width, background etc using JS.

Answer (score -1):

If you want change colors you should write your main.css;

```
#magicPointer{
   background-color: #000 !important;}
#magicMouseCursor{
  border: 1px solid #000 !important;}
```

Comment: Not best practise to use !important. also your formatting is a little off